# If an Arraylist<String> also contains numbers, how can I filter them out?

Tags: java, arraylist

ArrayList allRows imports values from a txt file. This file mainly contains Strings but there are a few rows that contain (only) numbers. I want to filter out those numbers and pass them to weightsOnly arraylist.

My code doesn't work because no value is filtered through the `for (int i=0; i<100; i++)`, eventhough the index 1 of allRows, for example, equals 60. Why doesn't my code manage to filter out these numbers? I just need to add those numbers to a separate arraylist.

```
public class UserInterface {
    private ArrayList<String> allRows;  //this ArrayList imports ALL the rows from the txt file            
    private ArrayList<String> weights;

    public UserInterface (){
        this.allRows=new ArrayList<>();
        this.weights=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void start(String file) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try (Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(Paths.get(file))){
            while (lineScanner.hasNextLine()){
                String row = lineScanner.nextLine();
                this.allRows.add(row);
            }
        } finally {
            process();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void process(){
        ArrayList<Integer> recipeWeights=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
            if (allRows.contains(i)){
                recipeWeights.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're inputting the data to a string array, so they are all strings even if they are numeric. You need to check if row is numeric, then add it to weights, else add to rows

Comment: Give some example data to make your question more obvious.

Comment: Giorgi, have you traced your code? I mean you add log lines to see what's happening after each operation.

Comment: @HoRn Use the debugger instead

Comment: @m0skit0 Oh, it's high-level

Comment: When you read a line from the file  String row = lineScanner.nextLine(); test "row" variable for numeric value like row.matches("^\\d+") if returned true then it is a row with number then added to the number list otherwise add it to the string list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`contains` also checks the type of the data,

so in our case you have to convert the `int` value to a `String`:

```
        if (allRows.contains(String.valueOf(i))){
            recipeWeights.add(i);
        }
```

Should work, if very row only contains the number